# UITableViewCell strange behavior when on select changing an image inside

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios5, uitableview

I have a problem while using a custom extended UITableViewCell with a nib file for a UITableView in my iPad application.
This cell have a behavior when selecting it to change a checkmark image from selected to unselected depended if it was selected, I use custom images for this and not the default check cell Apple have.
So everything in my functionality seems to be correct. I post some code.
I use the registerNib method to load the nib cell.

```
[tableView registerNib: [UINib nibWithNibName: @"ANibTableViewCell" bundle: nil] forCellReuseIdentifier: Identifier];
```

The nib cell is extended with a class file and managed through it, connecting outlets append model values etc.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView: (UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexpath: (NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
ExtendedtableViewCell* cell;
AModel* model;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: Identifier];
model = [modelForDisplay objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
cell.model = model;
// Some operations setting the check mark if it needed etc.
// Checkmark is a UIImageView in the nib cell that just changes image on selection
// Some other operations happening notified by the model if selected or unselected
return(cell);
}
```

My problem is so strange now, lets say that you visually have 6 cells and you select the first 3, all fine, but if you scroll down to see the next cells, lets say you scroll 6 rows down you notice that always per 6 cells the 3 first looks selected, but the extended cell class instance which I keep if its selected or not is not in selected state. What visual effect is that?

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly, the problem is:
Consider you have selected first 3 cells and rest 3 are in unselected state. Then you scroll down to see 6th cell, because the frame of your table is small enough to cater just 3 visible rows. When you come back to see the first 3 selected cell, it again deselects or something?

Comment: No, you scroll down and the 7th,8th,9th cells are selected for a reason, 10th, 11th, 12th are not and this goes on and on for all the records + the ones are already selected so a chaos happens.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *Identifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"cell%d.%d",indexPath.section,indexPath.row];


ExtendedtableViewCell* cell;
AModel* model;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: Identifier];
model = [modelForDisplay objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];
cell.model = model;
// Some operations setting the check mark if it needed etc.
// Checkmark is a UIImageView in the nib cell that just changes image on selection
// Some other operations happening notified by the model if selected or unselected
return(cell);
}
```

hope it will helps you.....

Comment: This crashes the app, I guess you forget that I use the registerNib UITableView method to register the nib file. Maybe if I load the nib inside the extended class to load?